# Ion-Spinner not showing on Infinite-Scroll when using ng-if

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

Good day everyone,

The issue is this:

when I put a condition for Infinite-Scroll the spinner and the text that shows loading ... is not showing. When I remove the condition, everything works perfectly. The issue also, that is the condition is needed as when all posts have retrieved no need to call the endpoint for nothing.

this is not working

```
      <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)" *ngIf="page < totalPage">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="تحميل المزيد من الأخبار..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

this is working

```
  <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="تحميل المزيد من الأخبار..."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: you are hiding the whole infinite-scroll by appling the ng-if! the condition should be moved inside the loadMore function i guess.

Comment: I am hiding when there are no more pages only but it is not showing even if the infinite scroll is not hidden

Comment: still no answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
     // this.page = this.page+1; // Remove this line because is hidding the spinner before api request is completed.
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.restApi.getUsers(this.page + 1) // Call api without changing the page yet
           .subscribe(
             res => {
               this.data = res; 
               this.page = this.page+1; // Add this line to hide spinner after api request is completed 
               this.perPage = this.data.per_page;
               this.totalData = this.data.total;
               this.totalPage = this.data.total_pages;
               for(let i=0; i<this.data.data.length; i++) {
                 this.users.push(this.data.data[i]);
               }
             },
             error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);

        console.log('Async operation has ended');
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! the explain is in the comments in the code.  The loading spinner is not showing because the condition *ngIf="page < totalPage"  is false before the api request is made. Lets say we have 2 pages. if we load the first page then page = 1 and totalPage=2, when the doInfinite method is executed page=2 and totalPage=2, this hides the spinner because 2<2 is false before the request is made, So you need to move the line this.page = this.page+1; from the first line to be inside the api response, this way the spinner will not hide . Greetings

Comment: Insert this explaining editing your answer, using the edit button below..

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the condition inside the `ion-infinite-scroll-content` tag. The below example worked well for me

Example:-

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content ngIf='yourCondition' loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data…">
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in Ionic v5:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll 
  (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)"
  [disabled]="totalPages <= 1 || currentPage >= totalPages"> 
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content
    loadingSpinner="bubbles" 
    loadingText="Loading...">
  </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

The disabled flag will only disable the loading spinner after the last page is reached. Once disabled, the infinite scroll will not emit additional "loadMore" events.
As somebody already mentioned, the page number should be updated only after your data is fetched (i.e. after loadMore API call successfully completed).